# HTTP2 server that responds any response code / frame

Tags: http, http2

What's the quickest way to setup an HTTP/2 server that can
1. dumbly respond any response code/payload at will
2. GOAWAY frame at will
3. stop responding to PING frame

Assume I have access to Ubuntu, RHEL, SUSE, or any Linux distro AWS EC2 offers (Debian, Amazon Linux, etc)

It needs to support both clear and TLS

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's what low-level HTTP/2 libraries allow you to do.